# How would you fix this "Promise<any>' provides no match for the signature '(value: any): {} | PromiseLike<{}>" Error

Tags: angular, promise

I am trying to user promises in order to do a synchronous execution.

I have followed the instructions listed in a github forum, with no luck.

```js
getData2(user: string, guid: string) {
  return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    //doing some stuff in here
    resolve();
  });
}

getData1(user: string, guid: string) {
  return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    //doing some other stuff in here
    resolve();
  });
}

userCheck(user: string) {
  //checking some array in here
}

userMethod(someArray: any){
  var i: any;
  var length = someArray.length;
  for (i=0; i < length; i++){
    this.getData1(someArray[i], userID).then(
      this.getData2(someArray[i], userID)).then(
          this.userCheck(someArray[i]));
      });
    })}
  }
```

The idea is that I want to first finish `getData1` and then do `getData2` and then do `userCheck`.

When I do it the way I have laid out above I get the error message:

```
Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: {}) => {} | PromiseLike<{}>'.
```

After fixing this issue I ran into the fact that the `userCheck` function is still executing before `getData2` finishes. I am not sure why. the `getData2` function looks like this.

```
getCCData(user: string, id: string){
    console.log('grabbing CC information', id, user);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        {
        this._apiService.getAssertion(id).toPromise().then(assert =>
{
    return this._apiService.getToken(assert.toString(), user);
}).then((data: any) =>
{   
    return this._apiService.ccMeta(data.access_token.toString(), id);
}).then(parseString(Promise)).then((information: any) =>
{
    this.ccData.push(
    {
        key: 'userStatus',
        value: information.entry
    });
});

    resolve();
        });
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to design this function. Any extra insight would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicates that `then()` expects a Function as parameter, while you provide it with the return value of another `then()` call, which is a Promise.

To resolve the error, change the calls inside the `then()`-calls to arrow functions:

```
for (const item of someArray) {
  this.getData1(item, userID).then(() =>
    this.getData2(item, userID).then(() =>
      this.userCheck(item)
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: While this is obviously just a mockup, I heavily recommend making use of TypeScripts typing capabilites - you can avoid lots of errors down the line if you never declare a variable, return value or parameter to be of type `any`, and always make sure to use appropriate types. If a variable can change its type (e.g. from `string` to `undefined`), then you can also set it's type to be either. E.g. `let param: string | undefined;`

Comment: Yes I understand. I did not want to incorporate all of my code so I kind of just hacked things here to give the basic premise of my goal.

Comment: I finally was able to get back to this issue and continue playing with it. It turns out that the userCheck function is still executing before the other two functions continue. Any ideas? @CGundlach

Comment: That's weird. The arrow functions inside then() shouldn't be called before the promise is resolved. Do you have more async calls inside the promises, like requesting files from a web server? If so, you need to wait for them, too.

Comment: inside getData1 and getData2 I am subscibing to a GET request. So I need to incorporate a then there as well?

Comment: I have made a few edits. Could you give me any advice on what my issue may be. @CGundlach